# Customise search form in the Widget

Tags: customization, widgets, search

I would like to customise the Search Form that you drag and drop from the widgets panel.

The customisation will be more than just css changes. I would like to add  and custom classes. Is this possible?

Is there a hook to customise the Search Field?

The only option I can think of is to create a custom search widget.

Comment: @ChinmoyKumarPaul, can you please make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your theme have not `search-form.php` file then you will create the file and add the custom css there. Because search widget is calling the **get_search_form()** function. First it will search the `search-from.php` file from activated theme folder. If there have no file then it will call wp's default search form.

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)

Answer (score 4):

If you landed here, it is `searchform.php` in WP v4.6.1