# Customise the Category Widget

Tags: customization, widgets

Similar to my [Search Widget question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156822/customise-search-form-in-the-widget)

Is there a way to customise the Categories Widget?
Again trying to add in extra markup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the parameters from [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) and the widget_categories_args filter

You can style the output with these CSS selectors:

```
 li.categories { ... }  
 li.cat-item { ... }
 li.cat-item-7 { ... }  
 li.current-cat { ... }
 li.current-cat-parent { ... }
 ul.children { ... }
```